# Is there a procedure for making umbrella questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I think there are a lot of related questions that could be turned in to umbrella questions.

One example:
How do I set environment variables for cron/upstart?

It could cover ruby, python, and bash for cron and upstart.

That way we could have one question/answer/set-of-answers to handle all upstart/cron environment variable questions.

This would enable something like redirecting [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117978/script-doesnt-run-via-crontab-but-works-fine-standalone/117989#117989), [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83549/python-script-wont-write-data-when-ran-from-cron), and [one of mine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105761/how-to-get-a-bundler-enabled-rails-app-running-as-a-service-with-upstart).  I just think it would be cleaner.

Comment: +1 Agreed, it would be a great reference to for those questions to be pointed at. Plus 12.04LTS and future ones as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure thing!

It does depend a *little* bit on what you mean by "umbrella questions".

For example, 90% of the ATI card questions we get are easily answerable by a answer with a link to Bruno's ATI card question plus a little extra elaboration on a particular point that is sticky.

Another one is our wonderful Unity configuration questions - we cover 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04, all in one question.

So in short, if you can do this, go ahead.

If you're interested in getting help with this, feel free to ping a mod and we'll do our best to help you clean things up. :)